# need new outlet

Tags: electrical

I have a 10 AWG (5.26MM2) 4 C 300040*C TO 90*C F12 water resistant line that was used to power an old tanning bed. It plugs directly into the wall outlet that that is ran from the breaker box to a 30 amp breaker and was hard wired into the old tanning bed with 4 wires just like the cord. The new tanning bed had a (UL) E-111452  12/3 SJTOW 105* C 300WFT-2  Water Resistant  --- CSA LL-81601 12AWG (8.8 1-MM)78 i THINK With a 3 prong plug. Can I use the old 10 gage wire and make an outlet for the new tanning bed plug. Does that make sense.

Comment: Should work in principle; change the appliance plug, no need to mess with anything on the walls unless you really want to. You may want some help wiring it up, though.

Comment: It voids my warranty if I cut the plug off

Comment: What is the nameplate rating of the equipment. Should be in amperage with a voltage, or a wattage .

Comment: I don't understand the question. You describe an existing outlet protected by a 30A breaker. What needs to be changed to plug in the new bed? Are you trying to use the old bed's wire as an extension cord?

Comment: using it as an extension cord is what I would like to do yes. That is if it's possible

Comment: Where would I find that information Retired Master Electrician

Comment: It would probably help to post photos of the wall receptacle, the old and new cord, and the informational nameplate (with amps and watts and stuff) on the new appliance, or at least its exact make and model number.

Comment: @TeenaLShaw -  All electrical equipment should have a nameplate and on that nameplate is all of the critical information about your equipment. In other words you should see something that says FLA (full load Amperage) or RLA (run load Amperage) beside it should be a voltage like 120V 120/240V or something like that or it might have a wattage 3000VA or 3KVA/KW. If you can't find that look at Harpers comment. We can figure out what size and voltage is required by the configuration of the new cord cap.

Comment: Old 4-wire, new 3-wire?  What country’s electrical system are we dealing with?  In the USA 4-wire implies 240v, 3-wire could be 120v or 240v.